# Two sequences defined by recurrence relations satisfy $x_n/y_n<\sqrt{7}$ for all $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations

Let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be two sequences such that:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1 \quad \text{ and } \quad y_{n+1}=x_n y_n$$
with $x_1=2$  and   $y_1=1$

Prove that for all $n$
$$\dfrac{x_n}{y_n} < \sqrt{7}.$$

Can I have any help with this situation?

Comment: Initial values for $x_0$ and $y_0$?

Comment: no there is no initial values

Comment: At least you should assume $\frac{x_0}{y_0} <\sqrt{7}$

Comment: even if we assume that you are thinking to solve it using recurrence but even u will face a problem by proving that

Comment: Gotta go somewhere, don't have time to think this through as an answer, but how about starting with$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{x_n}{y_n}+\frac{1}{x_ny_n}\ ?$$

Comment: we will not get anything from this

Comment: Starting from @David observation, we just need to prove that:
$$\frac{1}{y_0}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^j x_k}\leq \sqrt{7},$$ but obviously we need to know the values of $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Comment: i edit my question taking two initial values $x_1$ and $y_1$

Answer (score 5):

Given that:
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{x_n}{y_n}+\frac{1}{x_n y_n}$$
we have:
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x_n y_n}+\frac{1}{x_{n-1} y_{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_1 y_1}+\frac{x_1}{y_1}$$
or just:
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x_n\cdot\ldots\cdot x_1}+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_1}+2.$$
Hence we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^{m}x_n}\leq\sqrt{7}-2.\tag{1}$$
The form of the last inequality strongly suggest a continued fraction approach.

However, we can just notice that $x_1=2,x_2=5$ and for any $n\geq 3$ we have: $$x_n\geq 5^{2^{n-2}},$$
giving that the LHS of $(1)$ is less than
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{5^{2^k}}\leq \frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}=\frac{121}{200}.$$
Since $\frac{521}{200}<\sqrt{7}$, we're done.